# Apply autofocus on input inside ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to autofocus the first input inside `ngRepeat` when my page loads and when I add a new item to array the focus should go for the last item of the `ngRepeat` and so on, doesn't matter how many items I add.

Here's my code actually:

```
<div class="add-top" ng-show="showstep=='step2'" style="position:relative;width:100%;">
  <form name="EmailForm" novalidate accessible-form autocomplete="off" ng-submit="checkDup() &&  EmailForm.$valid ? Add() :''">
    <div class="white text-center ">
      <!-- && (emailDel | filter:'':true).length == emailDel.length -->
      <div class=" bg-color-upload03 ticket-top">
        <div class="col-md-12 " ng-init="emailDel=[1]">
          <div class="newevent-nav01">
            Enter email ids</div>
          <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3" ng-repeat="e in emailDel track by $index">

            <input type="email" class="text-left" placeholder="Email ID" validate-email ng-model="emailDel[$index]" ng-init="emailDel[$index]=''" ng-required="emailDel.length==1" name="email_{{$index}}" id="email_{{$index}}">

            <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-10 text-left" style="margin-top: -10px;" ng-show="(emailDel.length-1)==$index">

              <img src="../../../path to + symbol-active icon" width="40%" ng-hide="(EmailForm.$valid && emailDel[ds.emailDel.length-1] !='')" />

              <img src="../../..path to +symbol gray icon" width="40%" class="cursor-poi" ng-click="(EmailForm.$valid && emailDel[emailDel.length-1] !='') ? emailDel.push(emailDel.length+1) :''" ng-show="(EmailForm.$valid && emailDel[emailDel.length-1] !='')" />

            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12">
              <span class="error" ng-show="EmailForm['email_'+$index].$touched && !EmailForm['email_'+$index].hasFocus">
                          <span ng-show="EmailForm['email_'+$index].$error.required">
                          Required
                          </span>
              <span ng-show="EmailForm['email_'+$index].$error.email">
                          Invalid Email
                          </span>
              <span ng-show="emailDel[$index]!='' && (emailDel | filter:emailDel[$index]:true).length>1">
                              Duplicate Email
                          </span>
              </span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
          <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
            <button type="submit" class="btn" ng-disabled="EmailForm.$invalid || (emailDel.length>1 && (emailDel | filter:'':true).length==emailDel.length)">Continue</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you want to autofocus the first input?

Comment: yes. I require auto focus on first one as well as newly created one.

Comment: yes . First one should be auto focused. But when clicked on + symbol . New input email type has to automatically generate and focus has to be applied to that . It has to remove for first one and apply for newly created one. This has to happen every time i click on + symbol.

Comment: It seems the problem still remains the same. I am using angular js and controller for ng-click and javascript where ever required. Auto focus property not working

Comment: @developer033 for autofocus on load, just add to the end of <input> tag  autofocus. It should be like this : <input type ="email" autofocus> and it should work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create your own directive for this.

When it loads you set focus to the `$first` element of your `ngRepeat`, when you starts to add elements, the focus should go to the `$last`.

Here's a *snippet* working:

```js
angular.module('app', [])
 .controller('mainCtrl', function($scope) {
   $scope.email = ['test1@gmail.com', 'test2@hotmail.com', 'test3@stackoverflow.com'];
   $scope.init = true;
   $scope.add = function() {
     $scope.email.push('');
     $scope.init = false;
   }
 })

 .directive('setFocus', function() {
   return {
     scope: {
       setFocus: '='
     },
     link: function(scope, element) {
       if (scope.setFocus) element[0].focus();
     }
   };
 });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="mainCtrl">
  <form name="delEmailForm" novalidate accessible-form autocomplete="off" ng-submit="testing() && delEmailForm.$valid ? Add() :''">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 text-center" ng-repeat="e in email track by $index">
      <input type="email" set-focus="init ? $first : $last" class="inputbox-text-left" placeholder="Email ID" validate-email ng-model="email[$index]" ng-required="email.length==1 " name="email_{{$index}}" id="email_{{$index}}">
    </div>
    <button type="button" value="add" ng-click="add()">+</button>
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: can any one tell me why $('#email').focus(); is not working in this case.

Comment: Because it's a completely different thing.. have you tested my answer?

Comment: i am doing that now . Will update you very shortly. Thank you

Comment: Well, of course it's working, you can see it working above.. probably you didn't put in your code what I put here.

Comment: may be some other thing in my code is blocking it. I will try again. Is there any other way rather than directive. like simple $('#email').focus();?

Comment: Man, the correct way to achieve what you want is using a directive (which is not really hard). This `$('#email').focus()` is jQuery.. you're using Angular.. Also your requirement is not simple as this. Put your code equals to mine and it will work..

Comment: I am also using Jquery. I have tried that $('#email).focus()` and it didn't work eitther. So i went for angular to have a way of doing things in angular.

Comment: Well, do you know what `$('#email')` means?

Comment: email is id attribute in my input field  input type="email" name="email" id="email" ng-model="email". Please correct me if i am wrong

Comment: Yes.. but you don't have any id called 'email'.. but even if you have it doesn't meet your requirements.

Comment: yes it will be completely different every time since id="email_{{index}}". Always generating a new one. We cannot focus on one element

Comment: Yes.. that's what I'm saying.. the code I provided to you is really clean and useful....

Comment: thank you very much.  Let me check from my end why I am  facing the problem still

Comment: You can edit your question, and put at the end your full code.. maybe it's a simple mistake and I can help..

Comment: I have posted complete code like you asked. Can you help me here

Comment: Where is Js file? Also remove that `ng-init`

Comment: The JS is same as what you gave me

Comment: yes. Its all correct . I have other things working there as well..  Only problem is this.  When this form is loaded it automatically shows the required error instead of showing  it autofocus.

Comment: Did you removed that `ng-init`?

Comment: if i remove that it is showing as 1 and placeholder text is gone.

Comment: Well, `ng-init` directive should be used only for `ngRepeat` directive, not unuseful things like this.. anyway, I got what's is the problem then.. the problem is that you've a **required validation** and when page loads the input got focus (which is *correct* accordingly your requirements)... just took out the validation for a minute and see.

Comment: i tried that and still its the same. What should be done if i want both to be working

Comment: Place your **full** code here: http://plnkr.co/edit/Mj6fqDcoMGKQayW25aE1?p=preview and after save, send me the link, please.

Comment: Ok give me some time I will send you the link

Comment: This is the code : https://plnkr.co/edit/dJ1HzrYdQdiivOpKR5Hv?p=preview   Please read the read me file also . I have written something there clearly

Comment: You forgot toinstatiate `ng-app`, you forgot to put the angular script, you're using `ng-init` (which isn't for this kind of thing), and it's cleaning the inputs man, you forgot to use `set-focus` on the input.. in other words, you didn't almost nothing that I said.. Working version: https://plnkr.co/edit/b3xF1EABoGzUU7CYH8k3?p=preview

Comment: if we remove ng-init we are getting numbers like 2 3 and so on each time you click on add And also no autofocus on newly created input field. Is there a way to stop this. I have tested this in plunker only not in code. Will do that now.   https://plnkr.co/edit/dJ1HzrYdQdiivOpKR5Hv?p=preview

Comment: Well, your code is a bit messy.. you're using incorrect things, maybe a directive is in conflict with another... Also, can you please erase this comments to make the question clear? I'll do the same..